# Segurança em domain driven design

Tags: ddd

Em uma arquitetura DDD, em que camada se implementa a segurança (controle de acesso)?  Como ficaria a estrutura?

Comment: O controle de acesso pertence à camada de aplicativo. Nesta camada é tratado quais visões e serviços (falando de fachada de serviços para a interface e não do padrão *services*) o usuário ou outro sistema tem permissão de acesso. Não entendi a pergunta sobre a estrutura. Se você quer saber como tecnicamente isso é implementado é necessário informar a plataforma que você usa e o tipo de sistema que está desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

A parte de segurança deve ficar antes da criação dos eventos de domínio. Não é recomendado deixar a parte de segurança para interface pois você terá repetição de código.

Vamos utilizar o seguinte caso de uso (user story):

`O usuário pode editar seu perfil`

Teriamos a seguinte Domain Model de exemplo:

```
UsuarioService
editarperfil(EditarUsuarioCommand command)
    Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.getOneById(command.id)
    usuario.alterarNome(command.nome)
```

O controle de acesso deveria ficar antes da chamada `UsuarioService.editarPerfil()`

Alternativas para realizar esse controle de acesso:

- (IBAC) baseado em lista de identidades - recomendado para quando temos a lista de usuários e permissões

  ```
  UsuarioService
     @AccessControlList[listaUsuarios]
     editarperfil(EditarUsuarioCommand command)
  ```
- (LBAC) recomendado para níveis de acesso

  ```
       @posseses[level=5]
       userteste

      UserService
          @requires(level>=3)
          editarperfil(EditarUsuarioCommand command)
  ```
- (RBAC) baseada em papéis

  ```
      @roles[admin]
      userTest

      UsuarioService
          @requires(role=admin)
          editarperfil(EditarUsuarioCommand command)
  ```

Fontes

Mais sobre modelos de acesso [aqui](http://csrc.nist.gov/news_events/privilege-management-workshop/PvM-Model-Survey-Aug26-2009.pdf)

Discussão sobre segurança em DDD [aqui](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71847/with-all-of-these-services-how-can-i-not-be-anemic/71883#71883)

Pergunta sobre segurança em DDD [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464697/access-control-in-domain-driven-design)

Comment: Olá. Seria correto fazer no Cross cutting ou deve ser em infra?

Comment: No que diz respeito à user e role como ficaria?

Comment: A ideia é deixar a autenticação na camada cross cutting, pelo maior isolamento e reuso.

Comment: E como ficaria a estrutura? Pergunto isso porque tem as entidades e viewmodels, repositórios e etc